# Question regarding sort --key

Tags: sort

I'd like to sort a file, where sorting's key is a number in the second column, starting from the 2nd character of this column. For instance:

```
4 31
5 a14
2 h11
1 x4
2 z3
```

And the desired output is:

```
4 31
2 z3
1 x4
2 h11
5 a14
```

It seems like `sort -k` is a way to go, but it does not work as I would expect it to.

> k, --key=KEYDEF
>
> sort via a key; KEYDEF gives location and type
>
> KEYDEF  is F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]] for start and stop position,
>   where
>          F is a field number and C a character position in the field;  both  are
>          origin 1, and the stop position defaults to the line's end.  If neither
>          -t nor -b is in effect, characters in a  field  are  counted  from  the
>          beginning of the preceding whitespace.  OPTS is one or more single-let‐
>          ter ordering options  [bdfgiMhnRrV],  which  override  global  ordering
>          options  for  that key.  If no key is given, use the entire line as the
>          key.

I tried to do it like this:

```
sort -k 2.2V file
4 31
5 a14
2 h11
1 x4
2 z3
```

How to do it the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re running into this:

> characters in a field are counted from the beginning of the preceding whitespace.

```
sort -k 2.3V file
```

will give the result you’re after: the whitespace separating the fields is the first character of the second field.

Alternatively, you can add the `b` option to ignore leading blanks:

```
sort -k 2.2bV file
```

This allows the key definition to work with any number of blanks before the field.

Comment: thanks, that explains everything. I should read more carefully lol.

Comment: For those of us with GNU sort who also haven't memorized the man page, I find the --debug option helpful.